# Can you use variables for interface properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, discriminated-union

Let's say I have the classic example of discriminated union:

```
interface Circle {
  type: 'circle';
  radius: number;
}
interface Square {
  type: 'square';
  width: number;
}
type Shape = Circle | Square;
```

And then I throw it in a switch case:

```
switch (shape.type) {
  case 'circle':
    ...
  case 'square':
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to use variables to allow me to reference the discriminant in a singular way?

Comment: What do you mean "in a singular way"?  Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an enum. In typescript, variables are only used as values, whereas strings can act as both variables and types (e.g. 'circle'). See [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) for more info.

However enums also act as both variables and types, so in the example above, you could create an enum like so:

```
enum ShapeType {
  Circle = 'circle',
  Square = 'square',
}
```

And replace the type in the interface accordingly, for example:

```
interface Circle {
  type: ShapeType.Circle;
  radius: number;
}
```

and reference the enum in the switch case (e.g. `case ShapeType.Circle:` )

Answer (score 0):

You can define constants. Their types will be inferred as literal types. Then you can use `typeof` operator to get the type of the variable:

```
const circle = 'circle';
const square = 'square';

interface Circle {
  type: typeof circle;
  radius: number;
}
interface Square {
  type: typeof square;
  width: number;
}

type Shape = Circle | Square;
declare const shape: Shape;

switch (shape.type) {
  case circle:
    // ...
  case square:
    // ...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20circle%20%3D%20'circle'%3B%0Aconst%20square%20%3D%20'square'%3B%0A%0Ainterface%20Circle%20%7B%0A%20%20type%3A%20typeof%20circle%3B%0A%20%20radius%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0Ainterface%20Square%20%7B%0A%20%20type%3A%20typeof%20square%3B%0A%20%20width%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20Shape%20%3D%20Circle%20%7C%20Square%3B%0Adeclare%20const%20shape%3A%20Shape%3B%0A%0Aswitch%20(shape.type)%20%7B%0A%20%20case%20circle%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0A%20%20case%20square%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0A%7D)